# Spring Kafka onMessage receives duplicate message

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

We are using Kafka 1.0.0.M2 with Spring and we see a lot of duplicate message is getting received by the Listener onMessage() method .
We configured:

```
enable.auto.commit=false
session.timeout.ms=15000


factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
factory.setConcurrency(5);
```

So what could be the reason to get the duplicate messages?

Also we have different type of Topics so will we create different listener for each topic or one listener for all the topics.